# Why can't I write if (object is HashSet<>) but it's okay if I write (object.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<>))

Tags: c#, generics

The title says it all, here's the same with some formatting:

Why can't I write

```
public bool IsHashSet(object obj)
{
    return obj is HashSet<>;
}
```

but this is okay:

```
public bool IsHashSet(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<>);
}
```

(The same goes for **all generics** and isn't limited to `HashSet`)

Comment: probably the second method will never return true

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your function

```
public bool IsHashSet(object obj)
{
  return obj.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<>);
}
```

will return `false` for every possible value of `obj`, except `null`, in which case it will throw a `NullReferenceException`. It will *not* check if `obj` is a hash set. `typeof(HashSet<int>)` and `typeof(HashSet<>)` are two different types.

It is for that same reason that `obj is HashSet<>`  is rejected. It's completely useless. The only difference between the two functions is that one is useless in a way the compiler knows about, and the other is useless in a way the compiler doesn't know about.

You can use `type.IsGenericType` and `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`, then compare the result of the latter to `typeof(HashSet<>)`. However, you should ask yourself if that is useful: `obj is HashSet<int>` would also evaluate to `true` if `obj` is derived from `HashSet<int>`. Working with `obj.GetType()` would require you to check the class hierarchy yourself.

You can write a reusable helper function to check this for other generic types too:

```
public static bool IsInstanceOfGenericType(object obj, Type genericType) {
  if (obj == null)
    return false;

  var type = obj.GetType();
  while (type != null) {
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
      return true;

    type = type.BaseType;
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can call this as `IsInstanceOfGenericType(someObject, typeof(HashSet<>))`.

To respond to your comments:

> In my understanding of `HashSet<>` would mean `HashSet` of any generic, so maybe this would work `typeof(HashSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(HashSet<int>)`

It would not. It's possible you're thinking of Java, which as I understand it does have something like that, but C# does not. `HashSet<int>` and `HashSet<>` are related types, but their relation is not one related to inheritance.

> if not whats the meaning of `HashSet<>`

It is the `HashSet<T>` type before it has got any specific type argument. It can be used to construct the real types, for example after `var t = typeof(int);`, `typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(t)` can be used to get `typeof(HashSet<int>)`. It can be useful if `t` is not known at compile-time. But outside of such dynamic type construction, it is not meaningful.

> and why is it valid to write in a `typeof()` but not in `is HashSet<>`?

It's not valid with `is HashSet<>` because it would never be meaningful. It is impossible to construct any object whose type is `HashSet<>`.

Comment: I dont really get why the typeof(HashSet<>) fails, maybe you could explain it to me in more detail? I dont really care what generic it is and want the simplest possible check if its Something<AnyGenericType> (Do have to really write for all Generics a type static extension that checks the GetGenericTypeDefinition?)

Comment: @RandRandom If `typeof(HashSet<int>) != typeof(HashSet<>)`, and `obj.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<int>)`, then it logically follows that `obj.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<>)` cannot also be true. No, you wouldn't need to write a new method for each type you want to check, you can add that as a parameter. Will edit my answer to include that in a short while.

Comment: In my understanding of HashSet<> would mean HashSet of any generic, so maybe this would work typeof(HashSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(HashSet<int>) if not whats the meaning of HashSet<> and why is it valid to write in a typeof() but not in is HashSet<>?

Comment: It does answer my question to such an extent that I gave you +1 for 4 different answers aswell, especially the `typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(t)` looks really helpfull, thanks for all the info and the patience with a noob like me. :)

Comment: Oh, while I appreciate that, upvoting multiple answers only because of who posted them is actually something that is generally not accepted, and can result in action being taken against those votes. Glad to hear it helped, though.

Comment: So C# instantiates generics at compile-time just like C++ templates?

Comment: @C.R. If it happened purely at compile-time, then `typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int))` could never work unless the program contained a mention of `HashSet<int>` somewhere already. But if it happened purely at run-time, then `new(HashSet<int>).Add(3)` could not be checked by the compiler. It's somewhere in between, but the compiler pretty much does as little work as necessary.

Comment: @hvd: Seems more magic than both Java's generics and C++'s templates.

Answer (score 7):

Neither actually works, it's just that the first one will fail at compile time. What you probably want is something like this:

```
public bool IsHashSet(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null) 
    {
        var t = obj.GetType();
        if (t.IsGenericType) {
            return t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: Not sure why this gets a downvote. It's the same information I had added in my answer at about the same time you posted your answer. It could be improved by checking `obj == null`, and checking `t`'s base classes, but depending on what the OP is after, it may be good enough as it is.

Comment: @Selman22: The question as to why had already been answered. I was suggesting an alternative way to achieve what I presume is the aim of the OP. I assume they weren't asking for purely academic reasons, they are asking because they want to check if an object is a `HashSet<>`. Some times it's worth answering the real question instead of being pedantic.

Comment: @Selman22 It does (indirectly, but clear enough to me), by pointing out that the OP is comparing the wrong type to `typeof(HashSet<>)`.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks. I did notice right after I submitted that you answer had been updated to include the same information.